# How to determine if the JDBC driver supports PreparedStatement?

Tags: jdbc, prepared-statement

Is there a way to programmatically detect if the particular JDBC driver supports PreparedStatement without calling executeQuery() and catching "not implemented" exception?

Comment: Wait. Is there any driver not supporting prepared statements? That would be quite an unusable driver.

Comment: Call `Connection.prepareStatement()` and see what happens. If you got a `PreparedStatement`, it works. If not, not. You can't even get to the point of trying what you suggested. But I agree with @JBNizet that this is a non-problem.

Comment: You wouldn't believe how many half-baked drivers there are. Thank you for your idea of using try-catch just around Connection.prepareStatement(). Most "half-baked" drivers, like Hive (http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/hive/hive-jdbc/3.1.0/hive-jdbc-3.1.0-standalone.jar) are actually throwing at this statement, so screw the rest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any compliant JDBC driver must implement prepared statement. If you have a driver that doesn't support prepared statements, it is formally not a JDBC driver (even if it implements (part of) the JDBC API).

As the JDBC specification requires support of prepared statements, there is nothing in the API to check if they are supported. Contact the vendor/author of this driver and tell them that prepared statements are not optional. This unfortunately means that you can't discover it until you execute.

Also, I would be rather surprised if any driver not supporting prepared statements would allow preparing statements but only fail at execute time. This would - to me - suggest that prepared statements **are** supported (otherwise why not just fail when `Connection.prepareStatement` is called), but that whatever you are doing is not supported (like calling `executeQuery(String)` instead of `executeQuery()`).

Comment: He didn't 'refer' to any 'unnamed driver' that 'does allow preparing statements but only fails at execute time'. You made that up.

Comment: @user207421 True, I'm assuming here that the OP is confronted with a problem where a prepared statement `executeQuery` is throwing a 'not implemented', and looking for a generic way to detect and prevent it. Without that assumption, I don't really understand why this question would even need to be asked.

Comment: I don't see any reason for that assumption. It seems to me that he is just guessing. It is at least equally as probable as your assumption.

Comment: @user207421 Fair enough, I rephrased it a bit.